# "In [noun] terms" vs. "in terms of [noun]"

Tags: meaning, differences, word-order, modifiers

What are the differences in meaning between the followings?

> - In society terms
> - In terms of society

Comment: The first is rarer and probably unacceptable. The latter is more common.

Answer (score 2):

The general forms are either:

1. In terms of [Noun]
2. In [Adjective] terms.

So in your case, since the adjective form of *society* is *societal*, we would have:

> In societal terms.

Now we can also use a noun as an adjective, as you do with "In society terms".

Other answers and comments have suggested we wouldn't do so, but haven't explained why.

The reason, is that we while we *can* use nouns as adjectives, we generally don't, unless it gives us a benefit in some way (in particular, it often gives us a concise form where no adjective, or no well-known adjective, exists to serve).

Someone coming to express this idea might think of the adjective *societal*, or they might not.

If they didn't, they'd then likely use the "of society" form.

If they did, then they might decide that it being relatively rare, they should still use the "of society form".

Otherwise they'd use *societal*.

Your suggested "in society terms" is valid, and means the same thing as "in terms of society", but it's just not the phrasing we would normally expect. Most native speakers would be more likely to use one of the alternatives. If they did use "in society terms" they would also be likely to rephrase to one of the alternatives on revision, or have an editor make that change if it was in something that went through one.

Comment: Yes. You imply (but don't seem to say explicitly) that OP's non-standard "noun-as-adjective" example doesn't necessarily strike us as awful because we know that *societal* is relatively uncommon compared to *society*. Where the adjectival form is as common as the noun anyway, we're less tolerant. For example, most people would balk at *"in politics terms"*, given how easily *"in political terms"* rolls off the tongue.

Comment: @FumbleFingers conversely "spring break" is perfectly accepted, while "vernal break" would strike most as pedantic at best.

Comment: Surely that should be *correspondingly*, not *conversely*. We're more than happy with *spring break* and *summer holiday* because even those who happen to know *vernal* and *estival* are perfectly well aware that these words are nowhere near as common as the corresponding nouns.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard the first used. The second means something along the lines "With regards to society" or "Viewing it while considering society". It's tricky to translate. Do you have the whole sentence?

Answer (score 0):

It would be unusual to use *society* in this way. For a specialist readership you could use *societal* instead, but *in terms of society* will do for most purposes.